# Getting all the subclasses attributes

Tags: c++, qt

I am wondering what's the best way to get all the attributes of the derived class using pointers to the base class. The thing is that I have a method which gets all the Sport Games (base class) from the database. First I get all the football games, then all the basketball games and finally the tennis matches.

What's the best way to do it? If I return a `QList` of Sport Games then I will have to `dynamic_cast` them. Other way is to use the QProperty System and get all the properties of an object, assigning the attributes to the derived classes with the `Q_PROPERTY` macro. The third way I figured out to do it is passing three pointers to QList, one to each derived class and treat each one separately.

I have this doubt because I have always been told that in a hierarchy it's better to treat all the derived objects from the base class to take advantage of the hierarchy, otherwise it doesn't have sense (I think). But the thing is that I don't know what's the best way to get the attributes of the derived objects.

Comment: Not familiar with QT, so what sort of attributes are you talking about?  Attributes like member variables and setting them?

Comment: you know three ways to do it, so just choose the one you think works best. And just forget about what you were told what is better or not. Better is what works for you to get the problem solved. Applying rules just for the sake of the rules isnt very practical. Thats said, imho the question is too broad and without more context, a clear definition of what you mean with "better" and possibly some code it cannot be answered

Comment: @Curious Yes, sort of. But you can get all the properties from an object without knowing what properties it has, even if this properties were assigned to a derived object and you get them from the base object.

Comment: Getting all the attributes does not sound very OO. From outside, it is not intended to know them. Look at the context and think about what you really want. You don't actually want the attributes, do you? You want something like for example displaying information about all those games that is individually for every type of game. If so, declare something like `virtual string SportsGame::game_information() const = 0;` and implement it in each child class.

Comment: Asking what's "best" is more of an opinion question. It's not so much a StackOverflow kind of question IMO. Seems this would be a better question for  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The proper way is not to get the attributes at all, instead identify the thing you were trying to do with the attributes and ask the object to do that thing for you, without you ever knowing what these attributes are.